# How to debug MagickReadImage fail when no Exception occurs

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magickwand

I have some MagickWand code where the `MagickReadImage()` fails (returns `MagickFalse`) on one system where it works on the other.

Now there is no exception occuring, `MagickGetException()` returns an empty string which means no exception if I understood the documentation correctly.

The file I want to open is there, I can open it with other tools under the same user, and the `magick_wand` I use is not NULL.

The code around the call is essentially this:

```
    // read image
    MagickBooleanType status = MagickReadImage(magick_wand, fn_selector);

    // make sure it worked
    if (status == MagickFalse)
    {
            char *description;
            ExceptionType severity;
            description=MagickGetException(magick_wand,&severity);
            fprintf(stderr,"%s %s %lu :%s: %u\n",GetMagickModule(),description,severity);
            description=(char *) MagickRelinquishMemory(description);
            fprintf(stderr, "magickwand couldn't read file %s\n", fn_selector);
            exit(1);
    }
```

Is there any way to find out why the function call fails? `MagickReadImage()` seems to call an internal function which is not easily debuggable, and I don't want to build the MagickWand library myself with added debug stuff if not absolutely necessary.

Using MagickWand version 6.8.9.9 (debian jessie)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out (after going through an `strace`) the PDF reading part of ImageMagick requires the **ghostscript** executable (`/usr/bin/gs`) to be installed on the system. Now when installing ImageMagick via the Debian apt package manager, ghostscript is not a dependency, only a recommend of the Magick library. Unfortunately Magick does not think it's necessary to inform you in any way that a library component is missing when the read call fails.

After installing the `ghostscript` package, everything works as expected.